# Problem With Laravel Sanctum Token Security / Search of very well explained tutorial about Sanctum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream

I read the official documentation of Laravel Jetstream And Sanctum but I still don't understan a few things.

First of all, I secure the endpoint with

`Route::get('/endpointtoprotect', [AuthController::class, 'endpointtoprotect'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');`

So to use that endpoint I need the token from 'api/login'. I checked that and It's working. But when I put on purpose an incorrect token, it doesn't work but instead of returning me a 401 , it returns me a 200 to the login page with this code:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="wwDHIrOCqffknYEmWbOZi8ZQmlCRuCw2SfqdI0C5">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
        <div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col sm:justify-center items-center pt-6 sm:pt-0 bg-gray-100">
            <div>
                <a href="/">
                    <svg class="w-16 h-16" viewbox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            d="M11.395 44.428C4.557 40.198 0 32.632 0 24 0 10.745 10.745 0 24 0a23.891 23.891 0 0113.997 4.502c-.2 17.907-11.097 33.245-26.602 39.926z"
                            fill="#6875F5" />
                        <path
                            d="M14.134 45.885A23.914 23.914 0 0024 48c13.255 0 24-10.745 24-24 0-3.516-.756-6.856-2.115-9.866-4.659 15.143-16.608 27.092-31.75 31.751z"
                            fill="#6875F5" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="w-full sm:max-w-md mt-6 px-6 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">
                <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/login">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="wwDHIrOCqffknYEmWbOZi8ZQmlCRuCw2SfqdI0C5">
                    <div>
                        <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="email">
    Email
</label>
                        <input  class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm block mt-1 w-full" id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>

                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="password">
    Password
</label>
                            <input  class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm block mt-1 w-full" id="password" type="password" name="password" required="required" autocomplete="current-password">
            </div>

                            <div class="block mt-4">
                                <label for="remember_me" class="flex items-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50" id="remember_me" name="remember">
                    <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">Remember me</span>
                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                                <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900"
                                    href="http://localhost:8000/forgot-password">
                                    Forgot your password?
                                </a>

                                <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition ml-4">
    Log in
</button>
                            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>```

Does someone has a better tutorial or can explain to me basics of this sanctum authorization? It is supposed to be a built-in integrated solution but I don't see any simplicity about this. I'm seeing there is more documentation about JWT Tokens, but the functionality may be similar.
````

Comment: isn't it a desirable behavior to redirect user to login page if current user haven't login yet and tried to access a member area only page? are you sure it's returning 200 instead of 302 redirect to login route?

Comment: I would like to know 401 Unauthorized error because I'm using an api for Android Mobile so I need to get the specific error.

Comment: @Kristian - For an API, only an error should be returned and not a redirect. The client code should then process the error and decide to log in or report an error.

Comment: Exactly @JohnHanley. Can you help me with this? I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Default interface that JetStream prepares for you in the routing and welcome blade

Comment: Edit your question and show the routes in both web.php and api.php. Also show how you are making the requests.

Comment: If you are making a request on an `/api` endpoint, are you including the HTTP header `accept: application/json`?

Comment: @JohnHanley I can't believe it. It was the missing HTTP header "Accept: application/json"
Thank you so much! Now it's giving me the 401 with the JSON Content "message": "Unauthenticated." I appreciate!

Comment: You are welcome. I posted my suggestion as the solution/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

When making requests to `/api` endpoints, include the HTTP header `accept: application/json`.